# Is there any pdf library that supports arabic font?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, visual-studio-2015, arabic-support

I am working on final project for my bachelors degree. Well that a stemmer (Urdu Stemmer) Urdu is the national language of Pakistan.We write Urdu in Arabic font.I am trying to save the output in a PDF file. I was using itextsharp library but its not printing anything because it doesn't support Arabic font. So can anyone of you suggest me any other library that supports Arabic font.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string t = Stemtxtbox.Text;
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("E:/a.pdf", FileMode.Create));
    document.Open();
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph(t);
    document.Add(p);
    document.Close();
}
```

Comment: I haven't used itextsharp, but its source code contains hundreds of matches for terms like `unicode`, `arabic`, `RTL` and `bidi`. Are you *sure* it doesn't support Arabic?

Comment: I am sure that it iTextSharp supports Arabic. Why am I sure? Because I'm the original author of iText and I wrote a couple of iText books.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion here? http://geekswithblogs.net/JaydPage/archive/2011/11/02/using-itextsharp-to-correctly-display-hebrew--arabic-text-right.aspx

Comment: I bet Salman is using a font that doesn't support Arabic, which is something completely different.

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       
        {
            string t=Stemtxtbox.Text;
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("E:/a.pdf", FileMode.Create));
            document.Open();
            Paragraph p = new Paragraph(t);
           
            document.Add(p);
       
            document.Close();

        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `PdfPTable.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL` to indicate that you want to use the bidirectional algorithm. There's a similar property in `ColumnText`.